# Is there a drag and drop function in KivyMD or Kivy?

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

im really new in Kivy and i would like to make an app where i could create a MDIconButton that is draggable, and if possible, droppable in any BoxLayout? Is that possible in KivyMD or Kivy? Also is there a Kivy function where whenever I hold down a button, it'll display some kind of small dialogue box that contains details that can be entered by the user. thanks!

Comment: You can install Drag-N-Drop from kivy-garden. Refer to this https://github.com/kivy-garden/drag_n_drop

Comment: @FadiAbuRaid thanks! will this work well with KivyMD ?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use Drag-N-Drop from kivy-garden just use the `DragBehavior` class! It comes directly installed with Kivy and it'll save you having to install kivy-garden.

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.drag.html

Here is some example code of how it's used:

```
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder

# You could also put the following in your kv file...
kv = '''
<DragLabel>:
    # Define the properties for the DragLabel
    drag_rectangle: self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height
    drag_timeout: 10000000
    drag_distance: 0

FloatLayout:
    # Define the root widget
    DragLabel:
        size_hint: 0.25, 0.2
        text: 'Drag me'
'''


class DragLabel(DragBehavior, Label):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

TestApp().run()
```